# PHP return false with a string

Tags: php, string, return, boolean

I am looking for the correct way to handle a return statement with a bool/string. For example I do all my checking inside the function and return true if it all passes. However if something went wrong I would like to return a string of what went wrong rather than just return false; with a general string. Does php assume false if a var is set to anything besides true? What is the correct way to handle this? Here's an example of what I'm doing

```
<?php
$a = 2;

$result = CheckVar($a);
if ($result)
{
    echo 'Correct!';
}
else
{
    echo $result;
}

function CheckVar($var)
{
    if ($var == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return 'This is not the correct answer. You supplied '.$var;
    }
}
?>
```

It seems this method works, however is this good programming etiquette? Or is there another way I should be doing this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to understand *falsy* values in PHP (Javascript, also). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699507/why-use-false-to-check-stripos-in-php

Comment: @zzzzBov Exceptions are expensive. Don't throw an exception unless you have a very good reason to.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ, don't optimize prematurely. Yes, using many exceptions *can* be expensive.

Comment: @zzzzBov Using exceptions also uglifies your code. IMO it makes *no* sense to throw an exception if "the answer is not correct." Exceptions should be used to handle code that doesn't behave the way it's supposed to - thus the name "Exception." You fully expect the answer to be incorrect.

Comment: And I would know it. After all, I *am* an `Exception` :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does php assume false if a var is set to anything besides true?

Not at all. PHP will return whatever the variable was set to. And actually since you have a non-empty string, that's a "truthy" value (ie: `true` in a boolean context). Since you used `if ($result)` as your check and you return a "truthy" value, the condition is always true. You need to change that check to:

```
if ($result === true) {
    ...
```

> What is the correct way to handle this?

I think it's a good enough way to handle it. An alternative would be to pass an error string variable by reference, and have the fail part of your code fill that, eg:

```
function check($var, &$error) {
    if ($var == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $error = 'This is not the correct answer. You supplied ' . $var;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Some native PHP functions behave like this (eg: [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).) Yet another alternative is to return an array with the errors, like Jared suggested. I personally use this option when I expect multiple errors (eg: a form validation routine):

```
function check_stuff($stuff) {
    $errors = array();
    if (!$condition1) {
        $errors[] = 'Condition 1 failed';
    }

    if (!$condition2) {
        $errors[] = 'Condition 2 failed';
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Now you can also take advantage of the fact that empty arrays are falsy:

```
$errors = check_stuff($your_stuff);
if (!$errors) {
    echo 'No errors!';
} else {
    print_r($errors);
}
```

Comment: Although I have approached this in different ways over the year's, in this case I might want to return an array of errors from the function, and then test the return result for how many array member's it has. This way, I don't have to maintain two different contexts (the argument and the return value).

Comment: @Jared I also use arrays when I anticipate multiple errors (eg: a form validator).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `===` to check if the returned value is boolean true. `===` checks the type as well the value.

```
if ($result === true)
{
    echo 'Correct!';
}
else
{
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: This works well, though it seems pass-by-reference variables are better practicing standards. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I came up against this recently, my function would either return an error message as a string or return true like this:

```
function check_something(){
    if(condition){
        return 'error message';
    }
    // if we got this far all is good!
    return true;
}
```

I would call it and check the outcome like this:

```
$var = check_something();

if($var !== true){
    // $var is not boolean true, so it must be a string
    echo $var;
}
```

This checks that the outcome of the function is not just a truthy string, but is explicitly a boolean true

Comment: after coming back to this years later, it's a bad idea to have a method return a mixed type. there may be times when it's ok but as a rule you should always return only one type from a method, and throw exceptions for errors. This makes your whole stack a lot cleaner and easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful to someone returning true or returning false as a string.

```
if (is_bool($result)) 
{
   echo 'Result is a true bool';
} 
else
{
   echo $result.'returning a string';
}
```