# PHP - What is the difference between '!== false' and ' == true'?

Tags: php, evaluation

Sometimes I see people write conditional statements like this:

```
if($var !== false) {...}
```

Instead of like this:

```
if($var == true) {...}
```

These are the same, right?

I see the former used much more frequently and am wondering if there is a reason behind this, or if it is just personal preference.

I appreciate that this might be opinion based, but I am curious to see if there is a legitimate reason behind this.

Comment: i think personal preference

Comment: I would say using === true or !== false is probably preference based on readability of code and clearly depicting business rules without use of comments and such.

Comment: Also they are strict checking in the first one unlike the second suggestion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699507/why-use-false-to-check-stripos-in-php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768958/logical-operators-php-true-or-false

Comment: @UpsideDownRide this has nothing to do with `stripos`.

Comment: Anything "falsey" (but not actually `false`) will behave differently in the two cases - null, zero, empty string, etc

Comment: Why people prefer this is opinion-based, but this question asking if they are equivalent is *not* opinion-based. Either they are or they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not the same.

`!==` is a strict comparison that compares value and type. `$var` has to equal `(bool) false`. This means if a string of 'false' was returned it would fail.

`==` is a loose comparison that just checks the value. This means `$var` can equal '(string) string' and be true. When checking a var like this:

```
if ($var == true) {

}
```

you check if `$var` has anything in it/defined. As long as something is a against it (and doesn't equal `(bool) false`) it will pass the conditional. This means '(string) false' would pass that conditional.

Worth nothing some functions (like `strpos`) return `(bool) false` so doing the first one (IMO) is better for those sort of functions.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
 if($var !== false) {...}
```

will only evaluate to false if $var is exactly `false`. It will not evaluate to false if $var is any other value, whether 'false-y' or not.

This:

```
if($var == true) {...}
```

will evaluate to false for any 'false-y' value. e.g. `0`, `'0'`.

In addition this:

```
if($var === true) {...}
```

will evaluate to true only if $var is exactly set to true, not other 'truthy-y' values.

So you are correct that they are the same if you know $var is exclusively one of either `true` or `false`, but they behave differently for other values.

Answer (score 3):

`$var !== false` could be used for something other than readability or personal preference. Various PHP functions are expected to return `false` in case of error **and they might as well return a falsy value on success**. Take [`strpos`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for example:

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

This means the function can return an integer, **even `0` if the needle was found at the beginning**, and `false` if needle was not found. You have to use `!== false` to check if the expression is `false`, not falsy.

Answer (score -1):

> When you use ==

First, it typecast the variable and compare are those values same.
You can see in the following example

```
var_dump(0==FALSE);  // ( 0 == ( int ) false  )  bool(true) 
var_dump(0=='anystring'); //  ( 0 == ( int ) 'anystring' ) bool(true)
```

> When you use ===

It compares the value and types too

So it would be something like

```
var_dump(  gettype( 0  )  == gettype( false  ) && 0 == false  )
```

This is faster in case if your type check fails Since it has not to typecast the value for further 'value check' if type check fails.